# Cube root is a multifunction with three-fold ambiguity

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having a hard time convincing myself that the cube root function $(z)^{\frac13}$  has three fold ambiguity.

This is how I have been thinking about it:

Consider the mapping $z \mapsto z^3$, and for the sake of visualization let us restrict $z$ to a circle of radius $R$. Then $z \mapsto z^3$ maps the circle of radius $R$ to a circle with radius $R^3$ and increases the angular speed around the circle by a factor of $3$.

Now consider a point on the circle of radius $R^3$, the pre-image would correspond to the cube root mapping. To show that the cube root is indeed a multifunction the pre-image of any point $p$ on the circle of radius $R^3$ would contain three distinct points. However, I don't quite see how this is the case.

How can I visually see that the cube root at three-fold ambiguity using my example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $z=re^{i\theta}$ (for unique $r\in \mathbb R^+$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ ) is a non-zero complex number. Then if there is an element $w=\rho e^{i\psi}$ such that $z=w^3$,  we have $w^3=\rho^3e^{3i\psi}=re^{i\theta} $ and so $$\rho^3=r \text{ and } 3\psi=\theta +2\pi k$$

Since $\rho,r$ are both real, there is a unique solution to the first equation. The second equation resolves to be $\psi=\frac{\theta}{3}+\frac{2\pi k}{3}$. But $k$ values differing by $3$ are going to yield the same complex number (because adding $2\pi$ to the argument does nothing to a complex number), so exactly three values of $k$ will yield geometrically distinct arguments and hence exactly three choices for $w$.